# Почему не работает QTimer?(часть 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Задавал уже сегодня такой вопрос, но, как оказалось, я, пытаясь сделать свой код более читаемым, опять слишком сильно упростил ситуацию. Сейчас я попытаюсь рассказать обо всем подробнее.

Мой код состоит из двух классов - `MyThread` и `MyWindow`.

В `MyWindow` создается окно приложения с единственной кнопкой `btn`. `btn` привязана к методу `new_thread`, который вызывает метод `choose_dir`. `choose_dir` вызывает диалоговое окно выбора директории и возвращает путь к выбранной директории. Если `choose_dir` вернул путь к директории, `new_thread` создает новый поток, который является копией класса `MyThread`.

В новом потоке я планировал извлечь теги каждого `MP3-файла` в выбранной директории.

Метод `choose_files` класса `MyThread`, перебирает все MP3-файлы в выбранной директории, передавая путь к каждому файлу методу `extract_tags`. `extract_tags` извлекает разные теги музыкального файла, в числе которых должна быть длительность файла. Чтобы извлечь длительность, я создаю `QMediaPlayer`, передаю ему путь к файлу, полученный методом `extract_tags`. После этого создаю `QTimer`, который должен вызывать метод `extract_duration`. В `extract_duration` должна извлекаться длина файла. Но, почему-то код метода `extract_duration` не выполняется.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как починить код ?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from pathlib import Path

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, directory, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.directory = directory

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run')
        self.choose_files()

    def choose_files(self):
        pathlist = Path(self.directory).glob('**/*.mp3')
        if pathlist:
            for path in pathlist:
                self.path = str(path).replace('\\', '/')
                print(self.path)
                self.extract_tags()

    def extract_tags(self):
        # тут достаю теги файла self.path 
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(self.path)))
        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVolume(0.0)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.extract_duration)

    def extract_duration(self):
        d = self.player.duration()
        m = d // 1000 // 60
        s = d // 1000 % 60
        self.length = f'{m:1}:{s:02}'
        print(self.length)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        print('CHOOSE DIRECTORY BUTTON: click')
        directory = self.choose_dir()
        if directory:
            self.mythread = MyThread(directory)
            self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
            self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.mythread.start()

    def choose_dir(self):
        # Вызываю диалоговое окно выбора папки
        print('dialog window')
        drive = Path().absolute().drive + '/'
        dir_1 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                           'Open a folder',
                                                           drive,
                                                           QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        if dir_1:
            return dir_1

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('THREAD: finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from pathlib import Path

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, directory, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.directory = directory
        self.length = None

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run\n')
        self.choose_files()

    def choose_files(self):
        pathlist = Path(self.directory).glob('**/*.mp3')
        if pathlist:
            for path in pathlist:
                self.index = 0   # +++
                self.path = str(path).replace('\\', '/')
                self.singlTimer.emit(self.path)
                # update
                while self.index != 1:
                    QtCore.QThread.msleep(20)
                    print('не хватает времени')
                if self.length:
                    self.extract_duration()
                # update

    def extract_duration(self):   # update
        print(self.length)   # update
        print('a')   # update
        self.length = None


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        print('CHOOSE DIRECTORY BUTTON: click')
        directory = self.choose_dir()
        if directory:
            self.mythread = MyThread(directory)
            self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
            self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.mythread.singlTimer.connect(self.on_singlTimer)
            self.mythread.start()

    def choose_dir(self):
        # Вызываю диалоговое окно выбора папки
        print('dialog window')
        drive = Path().absolute().drive + '/'
        dir_1 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                           'Open a folder',
                                                           drive,
                                                           QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        if dir_1:
            return dir_1

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('\nTHREAD: finish')

    def on_singlTimer(self, path):
        self.player2 = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player2.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(path)))
        self.player2.play()
        self.player2.setVolume(0.0)
        self.player2.durationChanged.connect(self.func_2)

    def func_2(self):
        d = self.player2.duration()
        m = d // 1000 // 60
        s = d // 1000 % 60
        length = f'{m:1}:{s:02}'
        self.mythread.length = length
        self.mythread.index = 1   # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: я правильно вас понимаю, что в дочернем потоке, в методе `extract_duration` после получения `self.length` вы хотите запустить длительную задачу (например запись в БД) ?

Comment: Да, в методе `extract_duration` будет вызов метода, записывающего все в базу. После этого будет вызван метод извлечения обложки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потоки  - дело тонкое :) Пока по другому не получается. Пробуйте.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from pathlib import Path

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)                          # str

    def __init__(self, directory, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.directory = directory
        self.length = None                                       # ++

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run\n')
        self.choose_files()

    def choose_files(self):
        pathlist = Path(self.directory).glob('**/*.mp3')
        if pathlist:
            for path in pathlist:
                self.path = str(path).replace('\\', '/')
                self.singlTimer.emit(self.path)                  # +++ self.path
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(500)                       # +++
#                self.extract_tags()
                if self.length:                                  # +++
                    self.extract_duration(self.length)           # +++

    def extract_duration(self, length):
        print(f'length !!!!!!!!!!!+++++++++++++++ {length}')
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(3000)  # <<<--- Запускайте здесь свою длительную задачу 
        self.length = None


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        print('CHOOSE DIRECTORY BUTTON: click')
        directory = self.choose_dir()
        if directory:
            self.mythread = MyThread(directory)
            self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
            self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.mythread.singlTimer.connect(self.on_singlTimer)            # +++
            self.mythread.start()

    def choose_dir(self):
        # Вызываю диалоговое окно выбора папки
        print('dialog window')
        drive = Path().absolute().drive + '/'
        dir_1 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                           'Open a folder',
                                                           drive,
                                                           QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        if dir_1:
            return dir_1

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('\nTHREAD: finish')

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def on_singlTimer(self, path):                                            # +++
        # тут достаю теги файла self.path 
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(path)))   # path
        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVolume(0.0)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)

    def func_2(self):                                                         # +++
        d = self.player.duration()
        m = d // 1000 // 60
        s = d // 1000 % 60
        length = f'{m:1}:{s:02}'

        self.mythread.length = length                                          # +++ !!!

        print(f'This doesn`t work :) ---> {d}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

я исправил ваш второй пример и он в принципе работает.

- НЕ НАДО делать атрибутами класса ВРЕМЕННЫЕ переменные, 
  (self.index и self.path)
- не надо делать `while self.index != 1:`,
  делайте так `while index:` или `while not index:`
- смотрите другие комментарии по тексту примера.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from pathlib import Path

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, directory, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.directory = directory
        self.length = None

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run\n')
        self.choose_files()

    def choose_files(self):
        pathlist = Path(self.directory).glob('**/*.mp3')
        if pathlist:
            for path in pathlist:
 #                self.index = 0                                               #---
                index = True                                                  # +++
                path = str(path).replace('\\', '/')                           # -  self
                self.singlTimer.emit(path)                                    # -  self
 #                while self.index != 1:
                while index:                                                  # != 1:
                    QtCore.QThread.msleep(50)                                 # - 20 + 50
 #                    print('не хватает времени', index, self.length, path)
 # ----> это должно быть в цикле  `while`                   
                    if self.length:
                        self.extract_duration()
                        index = False                                         # +++ да
 # ---->

    def extract_duration(self):   
        print(f' получен length -> {self.length}')   
        self.length = None


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        print('CHOOSE DIRECTORY BUTTON: click')
        directory = self.choose_dir()
        if directory:
            self.mythread = MyThread(directory)
            self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
            self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.mythread.singlTimer.connect(self.on_singlTimer)
            self.mythread.start()

    def choose_dir(self):
        # Вызываю диалоговое окно выбора папки
        print('dialog window')
        drive = Path().absolute().drive + '/'
        dir_1 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                           'Open a folder',
                                                           drive,
                                                           QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        if dir_1:
            return dir_1

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('\nTHREAD: finish')

    def on_singlTimer(self, path):
        self.player2 = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player2.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(path)))
        self.player2.play()
        self.player2.setVolume(0.0)

        # QMediaPlayer::durationChanged(qint64 duration)                    # !!!
        # Notifier signal for property duration.                            # !!!
        self.player2.durationChanged.connect(self.func_2)

    def func_2(self, d):                                                    # +++ d  !!!
 #        d = self.player2.duration()                                        # ---
        m = d // 1000 // 60
        s = d // 1000 % 60
        length = f'{m:1}:{s:02}'
        self.mythread.length = length
 #        self.mythread.index = 1                                            # --- нет


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Еще вопросы вызывает строка `QtCore.QThread.msleep(3000)`. Получается, я должен задать строгое время. Но, я же не знаю, сколько потребуется секунд тому или иному компьютеру на выполнение необходимого кода. Я думал, можно заморозить поток на неопределенный строк, а после выполнения моего кода размораживать. Я ни в коем случае не требую менять ответ, просто хочу немного разобраться

Comment: Если опять что-то непонятное сказал, я обновлю вопрос. Просто мне очень нужно понять ситуацию

Comment: @MAXIM045 1. `Первый раз код почему-то вывел 0:00.` - потому что комп был чем-то загружен и `150` оказалось маловато, поэтому предлагаю заменить строку `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)` на `self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.func_2)`

Comment: @MAXIM045 2. строка `QtCore.QThread.msleep(3000)` - это имитация какого-то вашего процесса. Вместо нее вы должны поставить свой кусок кода, запись в БД или что там вы собираетесь делать и вы ничего не должны замораживать.

Comment: Однозначно, без вашей помощи я бы застрял и не знал, что делать дальше. Я очень благодарен вам. Надеюсь, уже скоро буду реже вас мучать своми глупыми вопросами

Comment: @MAXIM045 ваши вопросы отнюдь не глупые. Они требуют более глубокого понимания и это скоро к вам придет.

Comment: Очень не хотел задавать еще вопросы, но есть одна деталь, которую не совсем понимаю. Я подумал, вдруг у вас будет свободное время, и вы будете не против помочь очередной раз. Строчка `QtCore.QThread.msleep(500)` нужна, чтобы выделить время на извлечение длины? Можно ли не задавать строгое значение времени? Просто я боюсь какого-нибудь бага. Если что-то запишется неправильно в базу, сломается весь плеер.

Comment: @MAXIM045 да, Строчка QtCore.QThread.msleep(xxx) нужна, чтобы выделить время на извлечение длины. С указанным временем (`xxx`), можно поиграться, но пауза должна быть! иначе не изменив/получив значение  `self.length`  мы пропускаем вызов `self.extract_duration(self.length)`? т.к. дефолтное значкние `self.length = None` и БД ничего про текущий трек не запишется, а мы переходим к обработке следующего `path`. Рано или поздно в БД что-нибудь не то - запишется :) У вас должен быть скрипт для корректировки БД вручную либо возможность сформировать БД с нуля.

Comment: Понял, жаль, что так все сложно, и нет метода, извлекающего длительность файла, путь к которому можно было прописать в качестве аргумента. Раньше думал, что такая возможность будет обязательно. Получается, что извлекать длительность в момент формирования плейлиста я из-за этого не смогу :( Я занимаюсь программированием всего около трех месяцев и пока очень боюсь любой работы с базами данных, поэтому, к сожалению, не смогу сделать описанные вами сложные для меня скрипты. Спасибо!

Comment: @MAXIM045 я уже вам писал, что ничего бояться не надо. Ничего не возможного - нет. За три месяца вы достигли хорошего уровня и вы должны понимать, что для достижения определенного мастерства - нужно время и действия, а не нашептывание себе, что я что-то не смогу.

Comment: Добрый день. Знаю, что разворачивать такой крупный диалог в комментариях нехорошо, но у меня нет иного способа связаться с вами. Сегодня ночью я почему-то опять стал думать об этом коде. Мне в голову пришла идея, что можно было бы выделять время компьютеру до тех пор, пока это ему необходимо. Сейчас я немного изменил ваш код и обновил вопрос. Честно говоря, я слабо верю, что могу придумать что-нибудь полезное. Уже достаточно долго ищу подвох и хотел бы вас попросить посмотреть мой код и сказать, почему от такого варианта лучше отказаться

Comment: @MAXIM045   я прокомментировал ваш второй пример

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Я надеюсь, что так код стал немного надежнее :)